Another general form of beta function evaluation

Is there a general formula for this integral, $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^a (1-x)^b}{(c+hx)^{a+b+2}}dx$$

I encountered an integral which broke into two smaller integrals and both of them were of the above form.
I am going to write just one here, where the power of $x$ wasn't $0$.


$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}} (1-x)^\frac{-1}{2}}{(1+x)^{2}}dx$$

We will rewrite this as $$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^{\frac12}\cdot\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{\frac{-1}2}\cdot\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$$
Now we'll substitute $\frac{x}{1+x}=t$ 
After all simplifications, it will transform into
$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2} t^{\frac12} (1-2t)^{\frac{-1}{2}}dt$$
Now we will put $2t=p$ and the integral will convert into $$\int_0^1 \frac{p^{\frac{1}{2}} (1-p)^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{2^{\frac{3}{2}}}dp$$ $$=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{3}{2}}}\operatorname{B}\left(\frac32,\frac12\right)$$

I wonder if we take any general liner polynomial in the denominator, can we express that also in terms of beta function$?$
I used the above approach and everything was going good, before I assumed $\frac{x}{c+hx}=t$ and tried to calculate $\frac{1-x}{c+hx}$ 
If $c=1$ then I am good but what if we are solving for general $c$ $?$
Any help is greatly appreciated.

See here for a generalization.

$$I=\int\frac{x^a (1-x)^b}{(c+hx)^{a+b+2}}\,\,dx$$ $$d=\frac ch \quad \implies \quad I=\frac 1{h^{a+b+2}}\int\frac{x^a (1-x)^b}{(d+x)^{a+b+2}}\,\,dx$$
In order to compute
$$J=\int\frac{x^a (1-x)^b}{(d+x)^{a+b+2}}\,\,dx$$
use
$$\frac{1}{(d+x)^{a+b+2}}=\frac 1{d^{a+b+2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-(a+b+2)}{n}\left(\frac{x}{d}\right)^n$$
So, $J$ can be defined in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function.
Have a look here for the antiderivative (there is a lot of simplications to be done taking into account the possible conditions).
Using it
$$\large\color{blue}{K=\int_0^1\frac{x^a (1-x)^b}{(d+x)^{a+b+2}}\,\,dx=\frac{\Gamma (a+1) \Gamma (b+1)}{(d+1)^{a+1}\, d^{b+1}\,\Gamma(a+b+2)}}$$
